# Как импортировать .py в другой .py на TeleBot?

Tags: python, telebot, импорт

У меня есть buttons.py:

```
from telebot import types
from main import bot

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def buttons_start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    but1 = types.KeyboardButton('Кнопка 1')
    markup.add(but1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ку', reply_markup=markup)
```

и main.py:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from config import TOKEN
import sqlite3 as sql #Позже будет нужен

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    channel_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='-1001974463696', user_id=message.from_user.id)
    if channel_member.status == 'member' or channel_member.status == 'creator':
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Привет')
    else:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Подписаться', url='ссылка'))
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Подпишись!\n\n'
                              'После подписки на все каналы, введи /start.',
                     reply_markup=keyboard)

bot.polling()
```

**Как мне можно импортировать buttons.py, чтобы в** *main.py > bot.reply_to* **можно было написать** *`('Привет!', reply_markup = markup)`*?
**Ничего не получается, может есть какой-нибудь способ, как у cogs в disnake?**

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 способа решения данной проблемы:

1. Вам нужно изучить структуру проекта, чтобы она была как по документации, чтобы вы могли использовать хэндлеры в других файлах.
2. Нужно удалить хэндлеры из buttons.py и оставить только кнопки, тогда buttons.py будет выглядеть вот так:

   ```
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    but1 = types.KeyboardButton('Кнопка 1')
    markup.add(but1)
   ```

main.py:

```
import buttons
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
 def start_command(message):
   channel_member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='-1001974463696', 
   user_id=message.from_user.id)
    if channel_member.status == 'member' or channel_member.status == 'creator':
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Привет', reply_markup=buttons.markup)
    ... # Ваш код далее
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек 